# Set environment variables grunt or grunt-exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-exec

I'm trying to use grunt-exec to run a javascript test runner with a deployed link variable passed in.

I am trying to do so by setting an environment variable `grunt.option('link')` using `exec:setLink`. In my `test_runner.js` I grab the variable with `process.env.TEST_LINK`. Unfortunately, it appears that grunt-exec won't run bash commands such as export(?)

Really, I don't care how the variable gets to my `test_runner.js` so any other ideas would be welcome.

```
exec: {

  // DOESN'T WORK: Sets env variable with link for selenium tests
  setLink: {
    cmd: function () {
      return "export TEST_LINK=" + "'" + grunt.option('link') + "'";
    }
  },
  // Integration tests, needs TEST_LINK
  selenium: {
    cmd: function () {
      return "node test/runner/jasmine_runner.js";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grunt-exec`, environment variables for the child process can be specified in the [`env` option](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec#properties):

```
exec: {
  selenium: {
    cmd: function () {
      return "node test/runner/jasmine_runner.js";
    },
    options: {
      env: {
        'TEST_LINK': grunt.option('link')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One thing to bear in mind is that if only `TEST_LINK` is specified in the `env` option, that will be the only environment variable for the child process. If you want the current process's environment variables to be passed, too, you can do something like this:

```
exec: {
  selenium: {
    cmd: function () {
      return "node test/runner/jasmine_runner.js";
    },
    options: {
      env: Object.assign({}, process.env, { 'TEST_LINK': grunt.option('link') })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this? It didn't actually work for me.

Comment: Not recently and not with your config, but I've used it before. It just passes the `env` option directly to the child process `exec` call. Anyway, I see you have solved your problem by putting setting variable in grunt process's environment.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using node `process.env['TEST_LINK'] = grunt.option('link');`
Then retrieved in my javascript with `process.env['TEST_LINK'];`